# Can Google Map's Place API be used to access 2010 onwards restaurant data for Bangalore, India?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, openstreetmap, google-earth

I am trying to download place data (specifically restaurants, pubs, bars and cafe) of a Bangalore, India over the period of 2010-2023. I am aware that Place data API of google maps can be used to access active restaurant data. However, I am not sure how to use it for accessing archived data. Data can be on a entity(restaurant/bar/pub/cafe) and year level.

Also, tried accessing such data using open street maps using the [opq and datetime parameter](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/osmdata/html/opq.html) but very few restaurants captured for 2010 Bangalore, which makes it questionable. So I am trying to find if google api be used to access old place data for Bangalore, India from 2010 onwards?

Comment: It's entirely possible that Google Maps wasn't yet gathering that kind of data for Bangalore in 2010.  Google covered their home (America) before concentrating abroad.

Comment: I understand. Then do you mean its possible to download some archival data (if not 2010, then 2015)? I would like to try it out to see 'how old' data is available.

Comment: Google Earth Pro can.  https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148094?hl=en